# list of list random shuffle in Python?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I'm trying to get a list of randomized element inside a list. Something like this:

```
[['3','1','2','4'],  
['2','1','3','4'],  
['3','1','2','4'],  
['4','1','3','2']]
```

Each row shall contain randomly shuffled elements of 1,2,3,4, so I thought to reshuffle it few times.

I have used the following [yes, could be in loop, but that is more clear I hope]:

```
import random
p1=['1','2','3','4']
p=[]

random.shuffle(p1)
p.append(p1)
print p

random.shuffle(p1)
p.append(p1)
print p

random.shuffle(p1)
p.append(p1)
print p

random.shuffle(p1)
p.append(p1)
print p
```

However the result was like that:

```
>>>
[['2', '4', '1', '3']]
[['3', '4', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '1', '2']]
[['2', '4', '3', '1'], ['2', '4', '3', '1'], ['2', '4', '3', '1']]
[['1', '3', '4', '2'], ['1', '3', '4', '2'], ['1', '3', '4', '2'], ['1', '3', '4', '2']]
```

What I've made wrong? How to do that simple task in proper way?

Comment: are elements always from 1 to 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending the **same** `p1` object you keep modifying.  Rather, append a **copy**!  I.e, change each

```
p.append(p1)
```

into

```
p.append(list(p1))
```

Comment: To help explain why you need to copy the list, you can [visualise the execution of the code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+random%0Ap1%3D%5B'1','2','3','4'%5D%0Ap%3D%5B%5D%0A%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(p1)%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(p1)%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(p1)%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(p1)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) - you can see the list simply contains four references to the same list.

Comment: And [the same visualisation for the version in the answer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+random%0Ap1%3D%5B'1','2','3','4'%5D%0Ap%3D%5B%5D%0A%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(list(p1))%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(list(p1))%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(list(p1))%0Arandom.shuffle(p1)%0Ap.append(list(p1))&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0).

Comment: That's The POINT! Thank you for such a simple solution :)